# Why is "У девочки есть всё" singular?

Tags: грамматика

I'm a little bit confused here.Duolingo says "У девочки есть всё" is "The girl has everything".

However... If "девочка" is "girl" and "девочки" is "girls" can't we translate the sentence as "The girls have everything"? Or is this some kind of an exception?[image]

Edit : I guess, it does the same thing for other sentences too.It said "The woman has cats" for "У женщины есть кошки" .I'm really lost here.Wasn't женщины = women and женщина = woman.Also кошки is plural too, but the sentence is still singular!?

Comment: In that sentence nouns are used in genitive case.  Singular form would be: "У **девочки** есть всё."  Plural form would be "У **девочек** есть всё."  You're probably confused because genitive singular in this case is the same as nominative plural.

Comment: you use "jack of all trades master of none" dictionary-disguised-as-translator. And it gives wrong translation. http://www.translate.ru/ translates the phrase as "The girl has everything". Even Google Translate does the job. Duolingo just confuses forms of the word.

Comment: "девочки" is the genitive form of "девочка", but at the same time but not in this case it's the word on itself, which is the plural of "девочка". The genitive of "девочки" is "девочек". **So here, if you see that the word is in genitive, and it is "девочки", then it's singular "девочка".**

Answer (score 5):

You should be aware of the fact that the structure "у кого-то есть что‐то "actually means "кто‐то имеет что‐то ". Thus if you have

> Singular:
>
> У девочки есть всё. = Девочка имеет всё. = The girl (one) has everything.
>
> Plural :
>
> У девочек есть всё. = Девочки имеют всё. = The girls have everything.

I think this list of prepositions and cases might be helpful.

> Именительный
> кто? что?
> Родительный
> от, до, из, без, у, для,
> около, с, вокруг, после, кроме
> кого? чего?
> Дательный
> к, по
> кому? чему?
> Винительный
> в, на, за, про, через
> кого? что?
> Творительный
> с, со, за, под, над, между, перед
> кем? чем?
> Предложный
> о, об, в, на, при
> о ком? о чём

Comment: This is a little bit confusing.So can I say the second ones safely? So иметь = To have... right? So, what's the difference between У меня есть... and Я имею...?

Comment: @Burak - "Я имею ..." is more formal/bookish than "У меня есть ..."

Comment: I'd sat "я имею" is not only very archaic, it is more like focused "i own" or "i possess" than vague casual "i have"

Comment: Does this answer the question?

Comment: What I wanted to show is : this transformation helps to see how many "девочек" there actually are, and proves the fact that "девочки " Isn't a plural form. I am far from advising to use it in colloquial speech.

Answer (score 4):

The rule is which form of a noun specific preposition requires. The preposition "у" requires genetive case of a noun. That is девочки/девочек for girl/girls.

Comment: This answers the question, not other ones

Answer (score 3):

No, "У девочки есть всё" does not mean "The girls have everything". The literal word-for-word translation is:

> У - by the side
>
> девочки - of the little girl
>
> есть - is
>
> всё - everthing

To see why the verb is singular, we can rearange the sentence into the subject, verb order familiar to English speakers:

> Всё есть у девочки.

The subject of the sentence is всё (everything), not девочки (of the little girl).

Duolingo requires the student to translate using good style in the target language. Frequently this requires a rewording of the sentence. This required rewording often completely alters its grammatical structure.

Answer (score 0):

"Всё" has only singular form, similar to "fish" in English. Compare: a girl **has** a fish. Two girls **have** plenty of fish. Or, **have** all the fish. (Though maybe one can use "fishes" for aquarium fish)

Comment: The question is about singular form of the word "girl" while Russian sentence has "девочки".

Answer (score 0):

"Girls have everything" would be "у девочек есть все." In your phrase "девочки" is not plural of "девочка." It's a form of a word that doesn't  have a direct analog English.